# Let $Z \subseteq M$, then there exists a finite subset $S$ of $Z$ s.t. $Z \subseteq \bigcup_{s \in S} B_{\varepsilon} (s)$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $M$ be a metric space and $Z \subseteq M$.

For any given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a finite subset $S$ of $M$ s.t.
$Z \subseteq \bigcup_{s \in S} B_{\varepsilon} (s)$.

implies the following,

For any given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a finite subset $S$ of $Z$ s.t.
$Z \subseteq \bigcup_{s \in S} B_{\varepsilon} (s)$.

I think that it's maybe a exercise about totally bounded or open cover and I have checked the textbook
, but still have no ideas how to prove it.

Can someone give a details?

Comment: Your title doesn't make any sense to me, and it is making it tough to get to the meat of the problem. Can you reword it?

Comment: Are your hypothesis and conclusion identical?

Comment: If I'm reading what you have written correct, you $A\rightarrow A$, which is trivially true.

Comment: sorry, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $\epsilon>0$. By hypothesis there is a finite $S\subseteq M$ such that $Z\subseteq\bigcup_{s\in S}B_{\epsilon/2}(s)$. Let $S_0=\{s\in S:B_{\epsilon/2}(s)\cap Z\ne\varnothing\}$, and for each $s\in S_0$ let $z_s\in B_{\epsilon/2}(s)\cap Z$. Show that

$$Z\subseteq\bigcup_{s\in S_0}B_\epsilon(z_s)\;.$$